# My program doesn't end

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new too c++ and I had to design a program that determines the first four triangular square numbers and the output is exactly how I want it to be, but it wont quit after its printed the first four. I can't figure out what it could be. I can't CTRL C because I will get points taken off. What is the issue here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Prints name line
    cout<<"*********** BY: ********"<<endl;

    //Initializing
    const int HOW_MANY=4;
    int num=1;
    int tsn=0;
    int z=1;
    int x=0;
    //How many TSN it will find and be printed
    while (x<=HOW_MANY)
    { 
        //
        int sum=0;
        for (int y=0;y<512;y++)
        {
                sum+=y;
                tsn=pow(num,2);
                //Tests if the numbers are TSN
                if ((sum==tsn) || (num+1)/sqrt(num)==sqrt(num))
                {

                    //Prints 1-HOW_MANY TSN and what they are
                    cout<<"Square Triangular Number "<< z <<" is: "<< tsn <<endl;
                    z++;
                    x++;
                }
        }
        num++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x` must never be incremented, which means that condition defining whether or not it runs must never be true. You'll need to do some debugging.

Comment: _I can't figure out what it could be_ check your `while` and `for` loops, because if done wrong they can run indefinitely!

Comment: Your problem is mathematical, not algorithmic.  The first five square triangular numbers are 0, 1, 36, 1225, and 41616.  With `y` stopping at 511, you will never reach the 6th square triangular number 1413721, so `x` will never be greater than 4.  Try `while (x < HOW_MANY)`, or increase the upper limit on the loop over `y`.

Comment: Unrelated: `pow` is designed for really nasty stuff like pi to the power of e. Using it to square an integer is massive overkill and probably very slow. Just use multiplication here. Due to floating point imprecision it can also give you the wrong number.

Comment: Look into learning to use your development environment's debugger. It often makes investigating errant loops staggeringly easy. Make a comment on what compiler/ environment you are using and no doubt someone will tell you what debugger you should be using.

Comment: You cannot test float equality and expect any sensible results.

Answer (score 0):

`x` begins at `0`. Every time you find and print a number it gets incremented. You'll continue this, so long as `x<=HOW_MANY`.

You say your program finds 4 numbers but keeps running. After 4 hits, `x` will be 4. Is `4 <= 4`? The answer is yes, so your program keeps running.

Either change the condition to `x < HOW_MANY`, or initialize `x` to `1`.

---

## EDIT

Did a little leg work, it turns out the sum of all the numbers in the range [1,512] is **131328**. The 5th [square triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number) is **1413721**.

This means after you find the fourth triangle number, you will **never** sum high enough to find the next one. This will result in the infinite loop you're seeing.

The answer above is still the correct fix, but this is the reason you end up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

If `x = 0` then instead of `while (x<=HOW_MANY)` you need write `while (x<HOW_MANY)`.

Answer (score 0):

`for` should be used for iteration and `while` should be used for condition testing.

The problem, as has been noted, is that your `x` condition variable is never being incremented to get you out of the outer loop. That's a logic error that can be avoided by using the appropriate control structure for the job.